# How to set the default value for StorageValue?

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I am trying set default value for StorageValue, but its giving error:

```
#[pallet::type_value]
pub fn DefaultRegistrationFees<T: Config>() -> u128 { 100u128 }

#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn profile_registration_fees)]
pub type RegistrationFee<T> = StorageValue<_, u128, OptionQuery, DefaultRegistrationFees<T>>;
```

Error:
lib.rs(81, 12): the trait `frame_support::storage::types::QueryKindTrait<u128, pallet::DefaultRegistrationFees<T>>` is not implemented for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::OptionQuery`

https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/runtime/storage#default-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to write:

```
pub type RegistrationFee<T> = StorageValue<_, u128, ValueQuery, DefaultRegistrationFees<T>>;
```

So to use a `ValueQuery` instead of `OptionQuery`.

the `QueryKind` generic of the storage determine how the storage should be handled when there is no value in storage. With `OptionQuery`, when no value is in storage the method `get` will return `None`. With `ValueQuery`, when no value is in storage the method `get` will return the value configured with the generic `OnEmpty`.
So when configuring a specific default, you want to use `ValueQuery`.